# How to join two tables from two different database and retrieving data from MSSQL using C# / ASP. how to manage connection string for that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

How to join two tables from two different database and retrieving data **from MSSQL using C# / ASP**. how to manage connection string for that?

I have two Sql Server databases d1 and d2 which are in the same physical server. d1 has a table address, d2 has a table telephone. I want to join them in a C# project, I googled and tried many ways, but all failed. If anybody can provide a simple but "COMPLETE and RUNNABLE" C# example project, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
[d1].[dbo].[address]:
id    name    address
1     Adam    add1
2     Bob     add2
3     Pete    add3
4     Hans    add4

[d2].[dbo].[telephone]:
id    addr_id    phoneNumber
1     2          632532
2     1          233257
3     4          343439
4     3          798111
```

addr_id is a foreign key with the reference to id of table address in database d1.

```
ConnectionString_d1 = "Data Source=ServerName;" + "Initial Catalog=d1;" + "User id=ui;" + "Password=pd;";
ConnectionString_d2 = "Data Source=ServerName;" + "Initial Catalog=d2;" + "User id=ui;" + "Password=pd;";
Certainly, you need change the two connection strings according to your own databases for the test.

SELECT t1.name, t1.address, t2.phoneNumber
FROM [d1].[dbo].[address] t1
INNER JOIN [d2].[dbo].[address] t2
ON t1.id = t2.addr_id;
```

Please don't just tell me the T-Sql statement mentioned above that only works in MSSQL Management Studio, doesn't work in a C# project. I need the simple but the COMPLETE Implementation of a C# console application that can be built and run, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Code added please refer below, now try to provide me the answer

Comment: Use 3 part naming to join to the table on the other instance.

Comment: Better to use LinkedServer/Openquery when executing your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution

Can easily write a stored procedure then call the stored procedure from C#/ASP code. DONE